# iPhone tethering failing with 169.254.x.x eth1 address

Tags: networking

I'm tethering my RPi4 to an iPhone running iOS 14.4 using `usbmuxd 1.1.1` and `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v8+ aarch64`. When I plug the phone in and look at the interfaces with `ifconfig` `eth1` appears but has link-local addresses `169.254.x.x` and `fe80::...` so doesn't work via the USB connection. If I use the same device (and cable) on a macbook it works fine over USB and if I tether via Wifi or bluetooth it also works fine. Only USB doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the network settings on the iPhone fixed USB tethering and assigned a valid `172.20.10.x` address. Currently on iOS 14 this is in `Settings > General > Reset > [Reset Network Settings]` and the phone will go through a restart immediately. I also attempted `[Reset Location & Privacy]` immediately prior to re-prompt for Trust on the device, however the network reset seems to have been the fix and immediately on reconnect the tethering worked.